# Angular $q.defer breaking after moving to 1.2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have this Angular snippet which was working fine under Angular 1.0.8. I just switched to 1.2 and now, although I don't see any errors, I get no objects in the html.

```
// --- CONCERNS FACTORY --- //
concernsApp.factory('ConcernService', function ($http, $q) {
    var api_url = "http://localhost:8000/api/";

    var ConcernService = {
        list: function (items_url) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: api_url + items_url}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.reject(status);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        },
    };
    return ConcernService;
});


// --- PROJECTS CONTROLLER --- //
concernsApp.controller('ProjectsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ConcernService) {
    // get all projects
    $scope.projects = ConcernService.list('projects/');

    ...
```

The $http method still works and data is an object which is returned upon success.

I have a feeling the problem is that the list method returns a promise rather than an object, but I am unsure of how to refactor my code so that it works as before - i.e. $scope.projects is a n object.

Comment: You're right -- `$scope.projects` will be a promise, not the resolved value.

Comment: Try `ConcernService.list('projects/').then(function(d){$scope.projects = d})`

Comment: Yes - after some fiddling that's exactly where I ended up. Not as concise as before, but it does the trick ;)